# Almost every point in a union A of measurable sets $A_n$ belongs to at most k of the sets. Show $m(A)\geq \frac{\sum m(A_n)}{k}$

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let $\{A_n\}$ be a collection of measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}$.  If $A$ is the union of the collection and almost every $x\in A$ belongs to no more than $k$ of the $A_n$ then I need to show that $m(A)\geq\frac{\sum m(A_n)}{k}$.

My idea:  For each such x, I would like to identify it with a sub-collection of $\{A_n\}$ in such a way that the sub-collections are disjoint.  A starting point would be the collection of, say, j sets that $x$ belongs to: $\{A_{x_i}:\ x\in\bigcap_{i=1}^j A_{x_i},\ 1\leq j\leq k\}$.  However, I can't see that such sub-collections must be disjoint and I am not sure where to go from here or if this will lead to a solution.  Hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Should the equality in the first paragraph be an inequality (to match the title of your post)?

Comment: Must be, otherwise it's clearly false.

Comment: Also the collection must be countable, otherwise consider the collection of singletons.

Comment: Thank you, I did mistype that.  It should be an inequality which I've fixed.  And yes, it is a countable collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Denote $\chi_B$ the characteristic function of a set $B$. Then $\sum_n\chi_{A_n}\leq k\cdot\chi_A$ a.e.

Comment: Thanks for your hint.
I see that if $E=\{x\in A:\ x\text{belongs to at most k}\ A_n\}$ then $x\in E$ implies your statement.  Also, I see that $\sum_n \chi_{A_n}\leq k\cdot \chi_A$ gives a way of relating $A$, $A_n$ and $k$ with the desired inequality.  But I don't see how to change the characteristic functions of the sets to their measures.  Do I need to use that $\chi_B$ is measurable for any measurable set $B$?  Thanks again.

Comment: @dsimo04 You are right in your coment that the inequality is valid for $x\in E$ (I added "a.e." to my answer, so it is correct now). Now use the fact that $\int\chi_Bdm=m(B)$.